# Plotting exp series with GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have to plot 2^number with gnuplot. My data looks like below

```
2 1
4 10
8 15
16 20
..
```

On x axis I want numbers to be of the form 2^power. I tries
`set format x "2^%L` but everywhere it is have 2^0 on x axis.
Please suggest some method.

Comment: Have you `set log x`?

Answer (score 1):

%L uses the current log scale, which defaults to base 10, so you need to enter:

```
set logscale x 2
```

to set it to base 2